# Would it be possible to do a "slow" translunar injection, lasting an hour or more

Tags: orbital-motion, rocket-science

Part of my sci-fi novel takes place on a spaceship with centrifugal pseudogravity (initially at ~1g), designed to make passengers comfortable on a week-long voyage to the moon. With that being said, I think it would somewhat defeat the purpose of this if they had to endure an additional g of lateral acceleration for 6 unbearable minutes while the craft performed TLI.

For comparison, the Apollo third stage produced ~1g of acceleration for ~350 seconds to reach the moon in just under 3 days with a delta-v of 3050-3250 m/s.

So with that in mind, how much less efficient would it be (would it even be possible?) for my fictional craft to accelerate at just under 1 m/s² to boost its orbit over an hour or more, thus providing the same delta-v of 3000 m/s plus change, with minimal discomfort to its passengers? Could a lower delta-v be required if it made the journey in a week instead of 3 days?

Comment: Starting from what parking orbit? Most orbits classed as Low Earth Orbit have an orbital period of some 90 minutes, so you've got a nontrivial interaction between the thrust and gravity (as opposed to a quasi-pointwise injection that changes your velocity on a timespan much shorter than the orbital period). If you want to start from a higher orbit with a longer period, then it would either need to be quite elliptical (which might be undesirable for a number of reasons) or you would need to spend some significant energy (and $g$-loads) to circularize at high altitude.

Comment: Low Earth, ~500 km. I'm imagining some sort of rotation mechanism (side-thrusters to turn the ship) would be necessary to keep the main engine pointed "down". I imagine this would be a trivial amount of fuel expenditure, but would it be as trivial as I imagine it to be?

Comment: Keeping the craft's orientation to where you want it is indeed a trivial fuel expenditure compared to the TLI burn, but the problem isn't the orientation - it's the velocity vector. Running a TLI burn when your orbit's velocity vector is pointing towards the Moon is a good idea, but attempting to TLI when the orbit's velocity vector is pointing directly away from where you want to go is just asking for trouble. If the orbit is long enough, you might "fall back down on the other side of Earth" before you make it to escape velocity.

Comment: I see. Then I suppose it could be a series of 1 m/s² burns lasting a few minutes each, thus giving it a mission profile similar to Beresheet or SMART-1. Could it still reach the moon in 7 days though? I ask because both of those had mission profiles in the order of months, not days.

Comment: There are probably mission designs like that, where the thrust too low for a single burn to get you out, but enough so that two or three burns on the upwards part of the elliptical orbit are enough to break you out. But that becomes a rather elaborate mission-design problem much more than "how efficient can this be?".

Comment: So, there is a reasonably tractable proof that you use less energy making a orbit change burn in a short time than a long one, but there is nothing that prevents you for taking a long, *long* time if you have the energy. This is what needs to be done if you have a very low acceleration. You can actually take more than an entire orbit about the task if you need to (and you have the power; solar powered ion drives?).